# advantages of using echo vs output class of CI using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am currently polishing my program, but I notice that it's a bit slow because most of it are ajax requests. My question is that, are there any performance issues with regards to using **echo** over using **CI output class** when using ajax?

assume this is my ajax request:

```
$.post(base_url+'ajax')
  .done(function(res){
      res = JSON.parse(res);
      alert('res.message'); 
  });
```

when using ECHO:

```
<?php
  function ajax_response() { // inside my controller
      echo json_decode(array('message' => "Hello world"));         
  }
?>
```

when using CI output class:

```
<?php
  function ajax_response() { // inside my controller
       $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode( array('message' => 'Hello world' ) ));       
  }
?>
```

I would truly appreciate your help. thanks!

Comment: I would expect the network latency and database access to be the main cause of 'slowness', especially with 'ajax'. You should measure the complete transaction before tuning the code.

Comment: @RyanVincent what do you mean by "measure the complete transaction"?

Comment: Measure where the time is spent from the user clicking a button to the data being displayed on the screen (one transaction). There are online services and browsers already have these utilities built in i think. [User Timing API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/usertiming/)

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks for this I don't know how to use this yet but I'll dig into it. :)